# python server with socket and thread only work for 4 hours

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have a server with socket, when client connect a new thread start to record the recive data in a mysql database, the script does it fine but i have a infinite while and the script only work for 4 hours i need the server work at least for 24 hours.

What can i do?

```
import time
import MySQLdb
import sys
from socket import *                     
myHost = ''               
myPort = 6250                           

sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)  
sockobj.bind((myHost, myPort))          
sockobj.listen(10)                      
print 'Server On'

def handleClient(connection):           
    time.sleep(0.1)
    while True:                         
        try:
            data = connection.recv(256)
        except timeout:
            break
        if not data:
            break
        if 'q' not in data:
            if ',' in data:
                dato = data.split(',')
                try:
                    db=MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='',passwd='',db='')
                    cursor=db.cursor()
                    sql = "INSERT INTO imei"+dato[1]+" (imei, estado, fecha, numero) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s')"%(dato[0],dato[1],dato[2],dato[3])
                    cursor.execute(sql)
                    db.close()
                except MySQLdb.Error:
                    db.close()
                    break
        try:
            connection.send('LOAD')
        except:
            break

    connection.close( )
    thread.exit()

def dispatcher( ):                      
    while True:                         
        connection, address = sockobj.accept( ) 
        try:
            thread.start_new(handleClient, (connection,))
        except:
            dispatcher( )

dispatcher( )
```

if i do the same script with fork it works for 4 hours too.

Comment: Where is your server running? Some companies will terminate long-running processes

Comment: What is your [`interactive_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout) in MySQL set to?

Comment: Your insert statement is an SQL injection attack waiting to happen!

Comment: My server is running in a VPS but when i had lest clients the server ran for 3 days

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/supervisor to make sure that it is running 24 hours.
Also, could you please copy-paste the traceback after this script crashes?

Comment: Exception KeyError: KeyError (-1208863040,) in <module 'threading' from 'usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored

Comment: These are the last two mistakes before crashes, thank you for your help